# multiple argument isn't working for me in Java

Tags: java, arguments

I am trying run this code but its not working for me to get multiple arguments.

```
public class apples {


public static void main (String []args) {
    System.out.println( average(43,56,76,4,32,3));
}
    public static int average(int...numbers){
        int total = 0;
        for (int x:numbers){
            total +=x;
            return total/numbers.length;
        }
  }

 }
```

Comment: Please let us know *how* the code isn't working.  What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want `return` statement

```
return total/numbers.length;
```

out of loop

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the `return` statement outside the `for` loop:

```
public static int average(int... numbers)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int x : numbers) {
        total += x;

    }
    return total / numbers.length;
}
```

This is because if you pass `0` arguments to the method `average()` you won't never enter the body of the `for` loop. So the method won't reach a `return` statement.

Comment: Well, that and it wuoldn't prodcue the correct answer with the return statement where it is :-D

Comment: Your answer is more correct; the OP is obviously getting an error telling them they aren't returning a value. I was just pointing out the obvious.